# slicing list omitting first element

Tags: python, list, hashmap, slice

I wanted to slice a list which is stored in hashmap and append it to a empty string with the first element not having an '-i' as prefix. my code is not working :

output required:

`str1= one.mp4 -i two.mp4 -i three.mp4`

my code:

```
lis1=['one.mp4','two.mp4','three.mp4']
mes1={'x':lis1}
str1=''

for vid in mes1['x']:
    for vid in mes1['x'][0:1]:
        str1+=vid
        break
    for vid in mes1['x'][-2:]:
        str1+=' -i '+vid
        break

print(str1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in one line using the `join` function of Python strings!

```
str1 = " -i ".join(lis1)
```

This will join every element in the list into a string with `" -i "` between every element.

Comment: `str1 = " -i ".join(mes1['x']) ` in this case

Comment: Then you can do `str1 = " -i ".join(mes1['x'])`. There will not be a `-i` in front of the first element if you use `join`.